# How to override CSS of RichFaces components with custom CSS

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I have a `<rich:popupPanel>` that I have to style. I have inspected the element and found that the following CSS is been used.

```css
.rf-pp-hdr-cnt {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Now I have made changes to this CSS and included this in my CSS file. However, my custom CSS is ignored and the original RichFaces style is read. How can I use my custom CSS and override the original one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that the selector is *at least* as strong as the original selector of the styles you'd like to override. So if the original styles which you'd like to override are been specified by for example `.rf-something-else .rf-pp-hdr-cnt {}`, which is a stronger (more specific) selector, then it would always get precedence, unless you add (ugly) `!important` attributes to every style being overridden.

Second, you need to make sure that your custom CSS is been loaded *after* the RichFaces one. Easiest way to achieve this is using `<h:outputStylesheet>` in the `<h:body>`.

```
<h:head>
    ...
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="custom.css" />
    ...
</h:body>
```

This way it will implicitly be relocated to the *end* of the HTML `<head>`, *after* all auto-included JSF/RichFaces resources.

#### See also:

- [W3 CSS2 specification - 6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specifity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)
- [Sitepoint.com CSS reference - specifity](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity)